# Wir treffen uns ..  "in der"  oder "am" .. Musterstraße 3?

Tags: grammar, preposition

Welcher Satz ist richtig?

> Wir treffen uns um 10 Uhr **in der** Musterstr. 3.

oder

> Wir treffen uns um 10 Uhr **am** Musterstr. 3.

Comment: am <-> definierter Platz, Ort

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Die Präpositionsangabe richtet sich bei einer Adresse oder bei einem Treffpunkt danach, um was es sich bei dem vereinbarten Ort handelt (siehe hierzu auch [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/2540/23)).

#### Gebäude, Straße, Grundstück: *in*

Eine Straße ist ein Raum, den man betreten kann, man geht also **in** eine Straße. Dasselbe gilt auch für das Haus *Musterstr. 3*, das man betreten kann und **in** dem man sich trifft. Man trifft sich auch **im** Zoo oder **im** Freibad.

#### Markanter Punkt: *an*

Anders eine Sehenswürdigkeit oder ein anderer markanter Punkt. Man trifft sich hier **an** der Friedenssäule oder **am** Rathaus (sofern man nicht einen Termin in diesem Gebäude hat und sich folgerichtig **im** Rathaus trifft). Wenn man sich **am** Bahnhof verabredet, dann ist der Treffpunkt also klar außerhalb des Bahnhofsgebäudes, sonst würde man sich **im** Bahnhof, dort aber vielleicht **am** Fahrkartenschalter treffen.

#### Plätze: *auf*

Wenn der Treffpunkt kein Gebäude ist, aber ein Platz, auf den man treten kann, dann kann man sich auch **auf** dem Marktplatz, **auf** dem Friedhof, **auf** der Kirmes etc. verabreden.

#### Bedeckender Treffpunkt: *unter*

Wird der eigentliche Treffpunkt bedeckt, so kann man sich auch **unter** einer Linde, oder **unter** der Musterbrücke treffen.

#### Treffpunkt in der Nähe: *bei*, *neben*

Sobald der Treffpunkt nicht exakt angegeben ist, aber man einen markanten Punkt in der Nachbarschaft angibt, kann man sich auch **bei** der Kirche oder **neben** der Tankstelle treffen.

---

Bei vollständigen Adressen ist also die folgende Angabe üblich, denn hier ist ja ein Gebäude gemeint:

> Wir treffen uns um 10 Uhr in der Musterstraße 3.

Comment: Ich muß schon allein für "bedeckender Treffpunkt" ein +1 vergeben ;)

Comment: You could potentially say "an der Musterstr. 3" - which would infer that you're outside. But it would still sound a bit strange. Observe that it is "an der" and not "am", as Straße is feminine.