# "Am Flughafen" oder "Im Flughafen"?

Tags: preposition

Als ich mir kürzlichst eine Erkältung zugezogen habe, hatte ich auch direkt schon die Ursache gefunden:

> Die Klimaanlage im Flughafen ist schuld.

Doch kaum hatte ich den Satz gesagt, stutze ich. *Im Flughafen*, warum *im Flughafen*?

Das Wort Flughafen ist definiert als:

> Größerer Flugplatz für den allgemeinen Flugverkehr [besonders den Linienverkehr] <sup>[DUDEN](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Flughafen)</sup>
>
> Mit Flughafen wird ein Start- und Landeplatz nebst Infrastruktur bezeichnet, auf dem normalerweise regelmäßiger kommerzieller Flugverkehr stattfindet. <sup>[WIKIPEDIA](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flughafen)</sup>
>
> Luftfahrt: Start- und Landeplatz für Flugzeuge <sup>[WIKTIONARY](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flughafen)</sup>

So gesehen ist die Klimaanlage nicht *im Flughafen*:

> Die Klimaanlage am Flughafen ist schuld.

Ein anderes Beispiel, wo es merkwürdig klingt, ist:

> An einer Großdemonstration gegen Fluglärm im Flughafen nehmen am 4. Februar Tausende Demonstranten teil. <sup>[FRANKFURTER RUNDSCHAU](http://www.fr-online.de/flughafen-frankfurt/bundesverwaltungsgericht-zum-flughafen-frankfurt--leipziger-richter-daempfen-erwartungen,2641734,11886102.html)(im Chronik-Block zum Februar blättern)</sup>

Ich hab mich im Gebäude noch nie über Fluglärm aufgeregt. Dagegen laufen Flugzeugeinweiser gerne mit Micky-Mäusen rum. Ist der Lärm nicht eher auf dem Flugplatz, oder eben *am Flughafen*.

> Siegburg organisiert Protest gegen Nachtflug-Lärm am Flughafen. <sup>[MEINESTADT](http://aktuell.meinestadt.de/siegburg/2012/02/29/24-3-siegburg-organisiert-protest-gegen-nachtflug-laerm-am-flughafen/)</sup>

Da ich mir unsicher bin, hatte ich folgende Überlegungen angestellt:

> Wir treffen uns im Flughafen.
>
> Wir treffen uns am Flughafen.

Beides ist gängig. Mit *im Flughafen* sagt man ansich aus, dass man sich im Gebäude trifft (zum Beispiel am Schalter), während *am Flughafen* überall dort sein kann, theoretisch sogar auf der Start- und Landebahn.

Zollkontrollen hingegen werden am Flughafen gemacht, obwohl diese stets im Gebäude durchgeführt werden.

> Zollkontrolle am Flughafen Moskau-Scheremetjewo. <sup>[SÜDDEUTSCHE](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/politik/flughafen-in-moskau-russischer-zoll-entdeckt-radioaktives-material-bei-iran-reisendem-1.1236818)</sup>

Auch wenn eine [Google-Suche nach *Zollkontrolle im Flughafen*](https://www.google.de/search?client=opera&rls=de&q=im%20flughafen%20arbeiten&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#sclient=psy-ab&hl=de&client=opera&rls=de&channel=suggest&source=hp&q=%22zollkontrolle%20im%20flughafen%22&oq=%22zollkontrolle%20im%20flughafen%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=30244l30322l5l30561l2l2l0l0l0l1l165l280l0.2l2l0&gs_l=serp.3...30244l30322l5l30561l2l2l0l0l0l1l165l280l0j2l2l0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=5945ae8e2ef9a5a0&biw=1920&bih=890) einige Treffer landet, sind hier zumindest keine/wenige *zuverlässigen* Quellen dabei.

Auch [NGram Viewer zeigt](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=im%20Flughafen,%20am%20Flughafen&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3), dass *am Flughafen* wesentlich gängiger ist als *im Flughafen*.

Eine ähnliche Frage gab es kürzlichst, [deren Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/2951/1224) hier aber nicht ausreicht.

> Gebäude, Straße, Grundstück: in <sup>(hier *im*)</sup>
>
> Eine Straße ist ein Raum den man betreten kann, man geht also in eine Straße. Dasselbe gilt auch für das Haus Musterstr. 3, das man betreten kann und in dem man sich trifft. Man trifft sich auch im Zoo oder im Freibad.
>
> Plätze: auf
>
> Wenn der Treffpunkt kein Gebäude ist, aber ein Platz, auf den man treten kann, dann kann man sich auch auf dem Marktplatz, auf dem Friedhof, auf der Kirmes etc. verabreden.

Ein Beispiel zu *auf*:

> Das Flugzeug landet auf dem Flughafen.

Das Flugzeug landet -imho- niemals *am Flughafen*, hingegen ist es durchaus gängig zu sagen:

> Wir landen am Flughafen Köln-Bonn.

Unabhängig davon, dass man mich (wahrscheinlich) nie falsch verstehen wird, ob ich nun im oder am Flughafen sage, man jedoch zumindest im Falle des Treffpunktes mit im und am den Ort etwas anders definiert, was ist korrekt?

Ist die Klimaanlage im oder am Flughafen und sind Zollkontrollen im oder am Flughafen? Ist der (Flug)Lärm im oder am Flughafen und arbeitet man eventuell sogar im oder doch nur am Flughafen?

Als Randnotiz: NGram für *in the airport* vs *at the airport* zeigt auch ein deutliche Tendenz, während eine einfache Google-Anfrage gleich viele Ergebnisse listet.

Comment: Ich würde vorschlagen, sich des Genitivs zu befleißigen: "Die Klimaanlage des Flughafens ist schuld"

Comment: Start- & Landeplatz ist aber nicht beschränkt auf Start- & Landebahn. So gesehen ist die Klimaanlage des Flughafens doch die im Flughafen. Sich am Flughafen zu treffen könnte auch in unmittelbarer Nähe bedeuten, wie dem Vorplatz - bei Flughäfen eher ungewöhnlich, aber sich `am Kino` zu treffen würde ich als, soweit sonst nichts gesagt ist, als `davor` interpretieren, nicht drinnen. Wenn das Flugzeug `auf dem Flughafen` landet sollte man sehen, dass man noch schnell rauskommt, bevor er einstürzt. ;) Der Fluglärm ist auch nicht im Flughafen, sondern die Demo gegen den Fluglärm ist es.

Comment: "Flughafen" und "Bahnhof" werden umgangssprachlich oft gerne gleich benutzt: Auch der Bahnhof besteht zum größten Teil aus Gleisen, die meisten Leute meinen trotzdem das Empfangsgebäude. Beim Flughafen ist es genauso, er wird auf das Terminalgebäude reduziert.

Comment: @tofro: Das ist Quatsch. Natürlich trifft man sich, wenn man sich im Bahnhof trifft, nicht auf den Gleisen. Dennoch wird der Bahnhof nicht dadurch auf das Gebäude reduziert. Ebenso ist der Flughafen in erster Linie ein Hafen, kein Duty-Free-Shop. Im Flughafen stehen 17 Flugzeuge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bezüglich der Klimaanlage ist wohl *im Flughafen* die richtige Variante.

Das ist etwa wie ein Kind in der Schule auch sagt *Ich bin in der Schule*, obwohl es gerade auf dem Schulhof steht, denn das Wort *Schule* beschreibt nicht nur das Gebäude ansich, sondern das ganze Gelände.

So wie man stets *in der Schule* ist, so ist man auch *im Garten* oder *im Park*. Folglich ist es auch mit dem Flughafen so. Der Flughafen ist ein Areal, innerhalb dessen man sich befindet. Wo man sich genau dort befindet, ist egal.
Das gilt zum Beispiel auch für einen Hafen. Ein Schiff fährt *in den Hafen* ein und ankert *im Hafen*. Und dafür muss es sich nicht mal in einer Werft befinden.

Demnach müsste aber auch ein Flugzeug *im Flughafen* landen und Flughafenmitarbeiter, die außerhalb des Gebäudes ihrer Arbeit nachgehen, auch *im Flughafen* arbeiten. Hier scheint aber, verglichen an Google-Suchergebnissen, die Formulierung *am Flughafen* eindeutig gängiger zu sein.
Interessant wäre es hier vielleicht mal vom Bodenpersonal eine Meinung zu hören. Würde jemand sagen, er arbeite *im Flughafen* oder doch *am Flughafen*. Ich denke, auch hier ist die Tendenz zu der Präposition *am*.

Spricht man nur von einem (kleinen) Flugplatz, so befindet man sich jedoch stets *auf dem Flugplatz*. Auch wenn man sich in der Zentrale, im Tower oder im Hangar befindet, so sagt man *Ich befinde mich auf dem Flugplatz*, solange man den konkreten Aufenthaltsort nicht genauer bestimmen will.

Ob nun Proteste, der Lärm oder die Zollkontrollen *im* oder *am Flughafen* sind, hängt letztlich noch davon ab, was man genau ausdrücken möchte. Man würde beispielsweise auf die Frage *Wo finden Zollkontrollen statt?* mit *Am Flughafen* antworten, hingegen die Frage *Finden die Zollkontrollen beim Betreten des Flugzeuges statt?* beantwortet man konkreter mit *Nein, die finden im Flughafen selbst statt.*

Comment: Der korrekte Terminus für ein Flugzeug lautet: Das Flugzeug landet auf der Landebahn (8L oder 26R des Flughafens EDDM), wobei 8L die Landebahn bezeichnet und EDDM die Kennung für den Münchner Franz-Josef-Strauß-Flughafen ist. In Bezug auf ein Flugzeug wäre im/auf dem Flughafen falsch.

Comment: Die Sprechweise mit "am" bezüglich Flughafen ist eben vom Ursprungswort "Hafen" mitbestimmt und deshalb auch anders als bei der Schule. Beim Hafen ist klar: Die Schiffe liegen im Hafen, die Häuser stehen am Hafen, und man trifft sich am Hafen oder auf einem Schiff im Hafen. Beim Flughafen passte das "am" eigentlich schon von verherein nicht. Entweder ist man auf dem Flugplatz oder im Flughafengebäude, "am" wäre hier eigentlich nur sinnvoll vor oder neben dem Gebäude. Hat sich aber nun mal mit diesem Erbe anders durchgesetzt. "Im Flughafen" ist sinnvoll, wenn man über das Gebäude spricht.

Answer (score 3):

Generell sind Varianten mit größerer Trennschärfe und Präzision vorzuziehen.

> An einer Großdemonstration gegen Fluglärm im Flughafen nehmen am 4. Februar Tausende Demonstranten teil.

ist ein gutes Beispiel, der Satz lautete besser

> ... Großdemonstration im Flughafen gegen Fluglärm ...

Dementsprechend wäre z.B.

> Klimaanlage in der Abfertigungshalle

gegenüber

> Klimaanlage im Flughafen

vorzuziehen.

Wichtig werden solche Feinheiten besonders bei juristischen, technischen oder wissenschaftlichen Texten. Im Alltag, bei Unterhaltungen, nehmen wir es nicht so genau, und das finde ich auch nicht schlimm.

Comment: Auch wenn durch das Umdrehen von *im Flughafen* und *gegen Fluglärm* der Satz ganz anders klingt, stellt sich auch hier die Frage, warum nicht *am Flughafen*.

Comment: Mit "am Flughafen" hätte ich in diesem Fall kein Problem. Sowohl zu "im" als auch "am" ließen sich Argumente (und Gegenargumente) vortragen. Für mein Ohr klingen beide Varianten gleich gut. Auch hier könnte man sich für mehr Präzision entscheiden, z.B. "... Großdemonstration in Terminal 1 des Flughafens" und hätte somit die im/am-Entscheidung elegant umschifft (oder überflogen).

Comment: @Em1: Die Demonstration fand offensichtlich im Flughafengebäude statt, nicht davor oder auf dem Rollfeld, daher kann man nicht "am Flughafen" sagen.

Answer (score 2):

> Klimaanlagen im Flughafen

Der Flughafen beinhaltet neben den Landebahnen auch die Gebäude (Dein Wikipedia-Link nennt es "Infrastruktur"). Die Klimaanlagen sind also *im* Flughafengebäude.

"Am" zu verwenden, käme für mich nur in Frage, wenn man die Klimaanlage von einer anderen an einem anderen Ort unterscheiden will. Nehmen wir statt der Klimaanlage einen Schnellimbiss:

> Ich war im McDonald's am Flughafen, nicht in dem am Bahnhof.

Gehen wir davon aus, das McDonald's befindet sich *im* Flughafengebäude bzw. *im* Bahnhofsgebäude. Selbst dann würde ich *am* verwenden (wie oben beschrieben), um die verschiedenen Lokale anhand ihrer Standorte zu unterscheiden.

> Zollkontrollen am Flughafen

Die Zollkontrollen finden zwar *im* Flughafen(gebäude) statt, aber äquivalent zu den Kontrollen *an* der Grenze, wird hier *am* Flughafen kontrolliert. Es ist nicht von Bedeutung, dass sie in einem Gebäude stattfinden, sondern es wird bezug genommen auf den Ort der Grenzüberschreitung (nein, in der Luft wird nicht kontrolliert ;).

> Lärm im Flughafen

hört sich mehr nach dem Lärm in den Gebäuden an.

> Lärm am Flughafen

drückt eher aus, dass der Lärm gemeint ist, den der Flughafen durch startende und landende Flugzeuge verursacht. *Flughafenlärm* hört sich allerdings besser an. Wir können im Deutschen Wörter aneinanderreihen, also lasst es uns auch tun :)

Comment: Du machst aber schon was entscheidenes. Du fügst *Gebäude* an Flughafen an. Wenn ich *im Flughafengebäude* sage, ist die Sache glasklar. Aber impliziert *im Flughafen* automatisch, dass wir vom *Flughafengebäude* reden oder ist es ein Fehler unsererseits, anzunehmen, dass Flughafen das Gebädue ist und der Flugplatz *nur dazu gehört*.

Comment: Wie gesagt, @Em1, die Infrastruktur gehört dazu. Die Gebäude gehören zur Infraktruktur. Und genauso wie wir "an dem" zu "am" verkürzen, weil wir faul sind, lassen wir hin und wieder auch Teile von Worten weg und sagen Flughafen auch wenn wir nur ein Gebäude meinen.

Comment: @JohnSmithers: Nicht der Lärm findet im Flughafen statt, sondern die Demo! In den 80ern fanden die Demos am Flughafen statt - nicht im Flughafen. Der Satz kann aber ohne dies Wissen fehlgedeutet werden.

Comment: @userunknown: Solange sie nicht *im* Flughafen stattgefunden haben ;)

Comment: @JohnSmithers: Verstehe ich nicht. Das ist es doch gerade - damals fanden sie im Wald am Flughafen statt, der zur Startbahn-West werden sollte; heute dagegen finden sie **im** Flughafen statt. Auch kann es einen Imbiss im Bahnhof und einen am Bahnhof geben.