# Warum wird Dativ hier verwendet?

Tags: grammatical-case

Warum ist es:

> Das Flugzeug landet auf dem Flughafen.

und nicht

> Das Flugzeug landet auf den Flughafen.

Comment: Weil das Verb *landen* einen Ort verlangt, und nicht etwa eine Richtung.

Comment: @Janka hmm, vielleicht verwandt (entfernt) https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4183/am-flughafen-oder-im-flughafen

Comment: Nein, da geht es um die richtige Präposition. Bei *landen* muss es aber in jedem Fall ein Ort sein, keine Richtung, egal welche Präposition man verwendet.

Comment: @Janka   Gut. Richtig. Aber man kann weiterfragen: Warum verlangt das Wort "landen" einen Ort und nicht etwa eine Richtung? - Die Antwort ist dann: "So ist das halt". Und dann hätte man auch gleich als Antwort auf die Eingangsfrage sagen können: "So ist das halt."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*auf* als lokative Präposition ist eine so genannte Wechselpräposition: Wenn sie mit dem Dativ steht, wird eine Lagebezeichnung ausgedrückt. Wenn sie mit dem Akkusativ steht, wird eine Richtungsbezeichnung ausgedrückt. Vergleiche: *Ich fahre auf der Insel.* (= Ich bin bereits auf der Insel und fahre.) *Ich fahre auf die Insel.* (= Ich bin noch nicht auf der Insel, fahre allerdings in Richtung der Insel.)

Wenn man etwas genauer schaut, lässt sich die Sache noch ein Wenig präzisieren: Bei der Dativrektion findet die im Verb kodierte Handlung während des ganzen vom Verb eröffneten Zeitintervalls an einem Ort statt; bei der Akkusativrektion gilt die Lokalisierung hingegen nur während eines Teilintervalls. Weil es bei sprachlichen Phänomenen selten nur schwarz oder weiß gibt, kann es bei dynamischen Verben allerdings manchmal vorkommen, dass eine besondere Betonung des Ziels den Ausschlag für die Kasuswahl gibt. In diesem Fall führt die Fokussierung zu einer gedanklichen Verengung des relevanten Intervalls - mit der Folge, dass die Lokalisierungsrelation dieses Intervall nun plötzlich zur Gänze abdecken kann, auch wenn das Verb an sich einen zeitlich ausgedehnteren Vorgang beschreiben kann.

Es gehört nicht viel Phantasie dazu, um diese Einsicht auf das Beispiel von *landen* zu übertragen. Machen Sie sich zunächst klar, wie stark die Zielgerichtetheit/-betonung in *landen* ausgeprägt ist. Folgt man dem beschriebenen Muster und verkürzt man das relevante Intervall auf die unmittelbare zeitliche Umgebung des Ziels (mithin: des Aufsetzens der Maschine), so bewirkt dies, dass die Handlung auch gänzlich in der *auf*-Region des Flughafens lokalisiert ist. Das rechtfertigt die Dativrektion. Ein anderes Beispiel für das Phänomen: *ein Bild an der* (statt: *an die*) *Wand aufhängen.*

Praktisch sind solche Grenzfälle nicht mit Sicherheit aus bestehenden Regeln bestimmbar. Als Deutschlernender wird man insofern nicht umhinkommen, einige dieser Anschlüsse einfach zusammen mit dem Verb zu lernen.

Comment: „Weil es bei sprachlichen Phänomenen selten nur schwarz oder weiß gibt, kann es bei dynamischen Verben allerdings manchmal vorkommen, dass eine besondere Betonung des Ziels den Ausschlag für die Kasuswahl gibt. In diesem Fall führt die Fokussierung zu einer gedanklichen Verengung des relevanten Intervalls...“ Das wäre beim später genannten „an der Wand aufhängen“ der Fall, richtig?

Comment: Ja. Im Grunde ist die sprachlogische Idee dahinter eben, dass in _auf der Piste landen/ein Bild an der Wand aufhängen_ das Ziel so stark eincodiert ist, dass die Rektion nicht mehr dem prozeduralen Muster folgt (vgl. im Gegensatz dazu: _ein Bild an die Wand hängen_ mit weniger zielgerichtetem Verb _hängen_).