# When to use bei, bei der, beim and in, im, in der?

Tags: preposition

Our lecturer split it into

> Institution: bei der, beim
>   Firma: bei
>   Stadt/Land: in
>   Haus/Gebäude: im, in dem

But I mix things up.

- How can "*in Büro*" be correct (is it a *Stadt*?)?
- Can anyone give a concise guide, reference or article about it?

P.S.: I do understand, that in this case we use dative and their gender forms are dem/der/dem/den correspondingly.

Comment: „in Büro“ is **not** correct. It’s „im Büro“. E.g. „Ich bin gerade im Büro.“

Comment: This is the best guide **I** know of: http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Artikel/Prep-Art/Gebrauch.html

Comment: Closely related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2540/is-there-a-rule-which-preposition-to-use-for-a-place

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keep in mind that you often **omit the article pronoun for a city's or a person's names** (like Berlin, or Peter, etc.). You do use an article for a building's name, however.

**Intitutions**

- bei der Verwaltung *fem.*
- beim Amt *obj.*

**Companies**

- bei Google (Google is a name, therefore no article)

**Cities**

- in Berlin (a name again)

**Houses/Buildings**

- im Büro, in dem Büro *obj.*
- im Empire State Building (named building)
- auf dem Empire State Building (means physically on top!)

It is *im Büro*, which is short for *in dem Büro* to be explicit. *Büro* means *office* and is not a name. Reading the question I'm not sure whether this is clear, sorry if it is.

Comment: In some regions - namely Bavaria - persons are addressed using an article. For example *Ich habe dem Peter das Buch gegeben* instead of *Ich habe Peter das Buch gegeben*. The phrase *Ich bin beim Peter* (instead of *Ich bin bei Peter*) is very common there.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I think this is not just some regions but most.

Comment: OK, that's true. You do agree though this is colloquial German, don't you?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure whether it is just colloquial...

Comment: what about events? z.B. "Im Mitarbeitergespräch" is correct?