# in derselben Firma/bei derselben Firma

Tags: preposition

In einer Aufgabe sah ich folgenden Satz:

> *Wir arbeiten in derselben Firma.*

Mir wurde beigebracht, dass wenn es um eine Firma geht, verwendet man die Präposition *bei*. (sie arbeiten beim selben Arbeitgeber, nur Person A in … (Filiale/Ortschaft) und Person B in … (eine andere Ortschaft). Bedeutet hier die Präposition *in* „im selben HAUS/Gebäude“ (ich meine dasselbe Dach über dem Kopf)? Könnte man auch *Wir arbeiten **bei** derselben Firma* sagen? Oder hängt der Gebrauch der Präposition *in* irgendwie mit dem Wort "derselben" zusammen?

Comment: Verwandte Frage (wenn nicht sogar ein Duplikat): https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5411/when-to-use-bei-bei-der-beim-and-in-im-in-der?rq=1

Comment: Eine [Firma](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firma) ist nur ein Name, nämlich jener Name, unter dem ein Kaufmann seine Geschäfte führt. Arbeiten tut man nicht beim Namen des Unternehmens, sondern beim [Unternehmen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unternehmen).

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich denke, im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch wird _Firma_ im Sinne einer Metonymie verwendet.

Comment: Sorry, ich wollte schreiben 'Es gibt "derselben" als eigenständiges Wort, aber hier sind jeweils die zwei Worte "der selben" zu verwenden.' - ist das auch eine Neuerung der n. dt. Rechtschreibung, dass das jetzt immer zusammen gezogen wird? Hatte den Beitrag schon editiert und wollte es hier kommentieren und suchte nach einem schlagenden Beispiel, wo "dieselbe" usw. angemessen ist (nach alter Rechtschreibung) und fand mich beim Duden widerlegt.

Answer (score 3):

Ob "in derselben" oder "bei derselben Firma", beides läuft auf das gleiche hinaus. "Bei" strahlt einen Hauch mehr Distanziertheit aus. Beim Wort "Arbeitgeber" dagegen hast du keine Wahl, "bei" ist hier die einzige Möglichkeit.

Comment: Im entsprechenden Berufsfeld hat man auch die Möglichkeit "in" seinem Arbeitgeber zu arbeiten. Als Chirug zum Beispiel :D

Comment: @infinitezero - Ich sagte: das Wort "Arbeitgeber".

Comment: Funktioniert doch trotzdem. "Gestern musste ich ausnahmsweise mal in meinem Arbeitgeber, also meinem Chef, arbeiten".

Answer (score 3):

Der Satz *Wir arbeiten bei derselben Firma* ist komplett richtig. Der Gebrauch der Präposition *in* hängt also nicht mit dem Wort *derselben* zusammen, man kann beides sagen.

Die Präposition *in* scheint jedoch mehr als *bei* anzudeuten, dass die zwei Leute am selben Ort arbeiten, da sie meistens benutzt wird um Orte zu beschreiben. Wenn die zwei Leute zum Besipiel an verschiedenen Orten arbeiten, die nur Filialen derselben Firma sind, dann wäre die Präposition *bei* weniger missverständlich.