# Is it "in die Kinderbetreuung" or "zur Kinderbetreuung"?

Tags: grammar

> [Ich gehe nie wieder in die Kinderbetreuung](http://www.zeit.de/gesellschaft/familie/2013-07/kolumne-familienglueck-kinderhotel)

I think this means, *I will never again [nie wieder] go to childcare*.

In English, likewise in many cases in German, the proposition to be used with *to go (gehen)* is *to (zu)*.

So why is ***in die*** Kinderbetreuung instead of ***zur*** Kinderbetreuung?

Comment: Good catch. I would tend to use *zur* as I would say "Ich gehe nie wieder zur Schule/Kindergarten" rather than "Ich gehe nie wieder in die Schule/in den Kindergarten". Though I agree to bouscher that "in die Pflege" geben is more common.

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2540/is-there-a-rule-which-preposition-to-use-for-a-place

Answer (score 1):

*zum* is short for *zu dem*. This would assume that *Betreuung* is masculine, but it is not. So *zur* (short for *zu der*) would be a correct choice:

> Ich gehe nie wieder zur Kinderbetreuung

[EDIT]

"zur" is just as good as "in die". I've experienced that in this context "in" has become the preferred preposition like in "in die Pflege" geben. That might have to do with the fact that somebody is being handed over *into* the responsibility and care of somebody else, in German *in die Obhut geben*. So maybe people might be distinguishing this from a casual visit to a, say, a friend.

Comment: edited to your instructions. now perhaps you would explain to me why in die... and not zur...

Comment: @indoxica See my edit.

Comment: Yes, already read and internalised the info.

Answer (score 0):

Both versions are correct, depending on the geographic region where you are:

If you are in Germany, you say

> Ich gehe nie wieder **zur** Kinderbetreuung
>   Die Kinder gehen **zur** Schule

Because when you say this in Germany, you are meaning "I go to the institution and I enter the building where it is located". When you say this in Austria, Austrian people will understand "I go to the building and I stop in front of the door. I do not enter the building."

I am born in Austria and I live there. When I was a young child (5 or 6 years old) I never did understand, why german kids say that they go *to* their school, but why they never was talking about going *into* the school. I really did believe (but not for very long time), that german schools only practices outdoor-education.

So, if you are in Austria, you explicitely have to say that you go *into* that building. So in Austria you say:

> Ich gehe nie wieder **in die** Kinderbetreuung
>   Die Kinder gehen **in die** Schule

The difference comes from different ways of thinking about institutions and their buildings: In Germany a *childcare* or *school* is a special kind of institution (necessarily located in a building). In Austria we think different: A *school* or *childcare* is a building (hosting a special kind of institution).