# When to use "bei", "in" or "an" with a job description?

Tags: preposition

The following three sentences use the definite feminine nouns in dative case:

> Der Mann arbeitet **an** der Tankstelle.
>
> Sie arbeitet **in** der Bank.
>
> Er arbeitet **bei** der Post.

---

**Questions:**

- When should I use *an, in* and *bei?* Or can I use more than one in some (all) situations?
- Is it the same for indefinite article *einer?*

Please provide examples!

Comment: Related but not answered for work place prepositions (hence no dupe!): http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2540/is-there-a-rule-which-preposition-to-use-for-a-place

Comment: isn't it `bei` or `auf` der Bank?? it sure means in the building, but not neccesarily "at" the credit institute...
Maybe auf is just a regionalism in my area?? also "Die Post" is a more idiomatic expression. there you cannot use indefinite Article.

Comment: @Vogel612: The _Variantenwörterbuch_ attributes this usage of _auf_ to Switzerland only; I also know it from southwest Germany, though.

Comment: @chirlu Well, I don't agree to the *Variantenwörterbuch* as I live far away from Switzerland (rural area close to Cologne) but I do know *auf* in this context, too. Though, I cannot say how common its use actually is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know if there is a rule. I use different prepositions, depending on context, for instance

> Sie arbeitet ***bei*** der (Deutschen) Bank.

or

> Er arbeitet ***in*** der Post (neben dem Bahnhof).

would sound totally ok to me too.

If you would have to come up with a rule, I would say:

> Say ***"in"*** if you mean the place or building *(**in** einer Bankfiliale, **in** der Poststelle, **im** Einkaufszentrum etc.)*
>
> Say ***"bei"*** in combination with an indefinite article, if you refer to a company or instituion *(**bei** einer Bank, **bei** einer Aktiengesellschaft etc.)* or in combination with an definite or without an article, if you refer to a *particular* company or instituion *(**bei** der Post, **bei** der Bahn, **bei** der Technik GmbH, **bei** Müller & Söhne etc.)*
>
> Say ***"als"*** if you refer to the profession *(**als** Postbote, **als** Bankangestellter, **als** Zugführer etc.)*
>
> Say ***"an"*** if you mean "near"/"close to" *(**am** Bahnhof, **an** der Ecke)* OR "working on" *(**an** einer Klassenarbeit, **an** einem Projektauftrag etc.)* OR if you refer to the location, but "in" wouldn't make sense *(**am** Bahnhofsschalter, **an** der Kasse, **an** der Rezeption etc.)*

Still, these are not absolute, static rules. Basically, you can use a lot of other prepositions too, for instance "auf":

> Er arbeitet **auf** der MS Princess (Schiff).
>
> Sie arbeitet **auf** dem Markplatz.

...or even:

> Er arbeitet **unter** dem Hauptbahnhof **im** Technikraum.

etc. etc. ...

Comment: You can also say *Er arbeitet an einer Tankstelle* without meaning a certain one or a certain company. The explanation for this (which I can't give either) is vague.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar The explanation you are referring to (meaning a certain company) was for `bei`, not `an`! Apart from that: of course it is vague! I don't think there's a rule, it's just for orientation. I also updated my explanation though...

Comment: I'm referring to the correct one :-) You say *say "an" if you mean "near" [...] or if you refer to the location, but "in" wouldn't make sense*. That is correct, but vague, as it doesn't explain the `an der Tankstelle` vs. `in der Tankstelle` (the latter meaning that the person never goes outside). And in that explanation you're saying that *working **im** Bahnhofsschalter* wouldn't make sense - it does. It refers to the fact that the person is sitting behind the counter, not in front of it. My comment wasn't criticism to you, but an explanation to the OP about there not being a clear rule.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I don't exactly agree. If you say "in der Tankstelle", it implies "at the cash desk", but "an der Tankstelle" implies all kinds of tasks like refueling/washing cars etc. (outside). And: you don't work "im Schalter" (inside the counter), but "an" (beside/at the counter).