# Preposition for "working at a university"

Tags: preposition

Usually we use the preposition *bei* to describe working at a company:

> Ich arbeite **bei** der Firma Siemens.

and the preposition *an* for studying at a university:

> Ich studiere **an** der RWTH Aachen.

What about working at a university? Should it be *an* or *bei* or others?

> Ich arbeite (als Professor/Dozentin/Hausmeister) _____ der Uni Heidelberg.

Comment: All of _an der, bei der, in der_ and _für die_ are acceptable with _arbeiten_. One might tend to prefer _an_ for professors.

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7873/when-to-use-bei-in-or-an-with-a-job-description

Comment: Interessant. Jemand sollte mal eine Umfrage beim nicht-wissenschaftlichen Personal machen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only "an der" is correct unless you're not teaching at this university, then you would work "für die"university.
If you would say, I work "bei der" university, then you'd only work nearby."In der" would be correct but it's pretty outdated to say.

Answer (score 0):

> All of `an der`, `bei der`, `in der` and `für die` are acceptable with
>   arbeiten. One might tend to prefer `an` for professors.

(Just as Crissov said in the comments)