# "Sich an/bei einer Hochschule bewerben" – Wie ist es richtig?

Tags: grammar

Welche Präposition ist richtig: *an* oder *bei*?

> Ich möchte mich gerne für den Masterstudiegang "XXX" **an/bei** der Hochschule ZZZ bewerben.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Beides ist gleich richtig. Soweit es überhaupt stilistische oder Bedeutungsunterschiede geben sollte, sind sie minimal. Pedanten könnten vielleicht argumentieren, dass *bei* "richtiger" ist, weil "an der Hochschule" in anderem Kontext bedeutet, dass man schon dort ist, Bewerbungen heute aber meist aus der Ferne stattfinden. In der Praxis wird das aber niemandem auffallen, weil beide Formulierungen gleichermaßen verbreitet sind.

PS: Die Präpositionen *an* und *bei* beziehen sich auf unterschiedliche Satzteile:

- Ich bewerbe mich für den Studiengang an der Universität. - *An der Universität* wird ein *Studiengang* angeboten. Ich bewerbe mich darum/dafür.
- Ich bewerbe mich für den Studiengang bei der Universität. - Ich *bewerbe* mich *bei der Universität*: für einen Studiengang, der dort angeboten wird.

Für den zweiten Satz wäre ein anderer Satzbau etwas natürlicher. Im Folgenden ist jeweils das, was zusammengehört, hervorgehoben:

- Ich bewerbe mich für den *Studiengang an der Universität*. (Englisch: I am applying for the *course at the university*.)
- Ich *bewerbe mich bei der Universität* für den Studiengang. (Englisch: I am *applying to the university* for the course.)

Answer (score 7):

Nach meinem Sprachgefühl bewerbe ich mich

- an der Hochschule
  wenn ich dort studieren möchte, aber
- bei der Hochschule
  um eine Arbeitsstelle.

Comment: Sehr guter Aspekt, den ich übersehen habe. Ich sehe es allerdings selber eher so, dass *bei* eine allgemeinere Formulierung ist, die für Arbeit oder Studium überall funktioniert, während *an* nur im Zusammenhang mit Hochschulen verwendet werden kann und deshalb nur für einen Studienplatz oder eine Stelle in Forschung/Lehre passt.

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17250/preposition-for-working-at-a-university/17251#17251