# What is the difference between in, an, and bei with buildings?

Tags: preposition

I would like to know the difference between these three statements:

> Ich war im Supermarkt.
>
> Ich war beim Supermarkt.
>
> Ich war am Supermarkt.

And I would like to know when do we use "bei" with places, for example what do we mean by this statement:

> Da drüber bei der U-Bahn-Haltestelle ist ein Supermarkt.

Note: This question is different from the pointed question (as a duplicate of it), they didn't explain there the difference between "bei" and "in" when we use them with places (and more specifically with buildings).

Comment: related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2540/is-there-a-rule-which-preposition-to-use-for-a-place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ich war **im** Supermarkt.

Implies you were actually in the supermarket.

> Ich war **beim** Supermarkt.

Implies that you were either inside or next to it, it would be mostly used if you have *a story to tell* rather than simply stating the fact of your location.

> Ich war **am** Supermarkt (angekommen).

Without any addition like *angekommen* it's not a good sentence (at least in High German). However with it, it means you might have reached the supermarket (stand in front of the door or something), but you don't express you've been inside it.

> Da drübe**n** bei der U-Bahn-Haltestelle ist ein Supermarkt.

The **bei** means here, *next to* meaning the supermarket is somewhere close to the subway station.

Comment: So can we say that "an" always implies that you are close to the door of the place, and bei implies that you are somewhere next to or beside that place?

Comment: @MohammadSaadeh well, **"am"** doesn't really imply you're on the door. On a second look the second example doesn't work as it is. I will edit that.

Comment: Then now I understand that "an" and "bei" can have the same meaning when we want to say that we are next to a place? And "bei" can be same as "in" when we want to express that we are inside that place?

Comment: @MohammadSaadeh "an"/"bei" appear indeed quite similar but they are not entirely. Especially "bei" is quite complex - (https://www.germanveryeasy.com/bei).

Comment: @MohammadSaadeh To your 2nd Q: "Bei" can have the meaning of inside. You could either say "Ich war beim Supermarkt einkaufen" or "Ich war im Supermarkt einkaufen", depending on what you want to **emphasize**: "beim" - the action "einkaufen", "im" - the location "Supermarkt".

Answer (score 1):

Note:

- im = in dem (*in the*)
- beim = bei dem (*at the*)
- am = an dem (*on the* or *at the*)

---

**im = in dem**

> Ich war im Supermarkt.
>   I was in the supermarket.

You entered the shop, i.e you were inside it.

---

**beim = bei dem**

> Ich war beim Supermarkt.
>   I was at the supermarket.

In most cases this also means, that you were in the market, but you also could have been there and found it closed:

> Ich war beim Supermarkt, aber er hatte zu.
>   I was at the supermarket, but it was closed.

---

**am = an dem (regional also: auf dem)**

You normally won't use *am* in such a sentence, because it doesn't make much sense:

> Ich war am Supermarkt.
>   I was on the supermarket.

In Austria *»am«* can also mean *»auf dem«* (like in *[St. Anton am Arlberg](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Anton_am_Arlberg)*). In this case this sentence means that you was standing on the roof of the market.

In the rest of the German spoken area *»am«* only means *»an dem«* (like in *[Velden am Wörther See](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velden_am_W%C3%B6rther_See)*) which in most contexts means "beside" or "close to". But this doesn't make much sense fort a supermarket.

---

If the grammatical gender of the location is feminine, there is no short form of preposition+article. There is no short form for *»bei der«* (the word *beir* doesn't exist), so you have to use the long form:

**neuter**
das Haus, das Arbeitsamt, das Gerüst

> Ich war im Haus. = Ich war in dem Haus.
>   Ich war beim Arbeitsamt. = Ich war bei dem Arbeitsamt.
>   Das Plakat klebt am Gerüst. = Das Plakat klebt an dem Gerüst.

**masculine**
der Palast, der Schuster, der Pfeiler

> Ich war im Palast. = Ich war in dem Palast.
>   Ich war beim Schuster. = Ich war bei dem Schuster.
>   Das Plakat klebt am Pfeiler. = Das Plakat klebt an dem Pfeiler.

**feminine**
die Hütte, die Wäscherei, die Wand

> Ich war in der Hütte.
>   Ich war bei der Wäscherei.
>   Das Plakat klebt an der Wand.

Comment: St. Anton liegt doch nicht **auf** dem Arlberg sondern **am** Fuße des Arlbergs... oder? Bild vom Arlberg: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Arlberg_passstrasse.jpg - da steht kein Haus.

Comment: Aber es stimmt schon, man kann in Österreich sagen: *Ich bin **am** Topf g'sessen.* während ein Deutscher **auf** demselben säße.

Comment: @Takkat: Der [Arlberg](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arlberg) hat keinen Gipfel, denn das ist kein Berg (im heutigen Sinn des Wortes), sondern ein Pass. Seine höchste Stelle liegt 1793 Meter über dem Meer. Kaum 50 oder 100 Meter von dieser höchsten Stelle entfernt beginnt der kleine Ort [St. Christoph am Arlberg](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Christoph_am_Arlberg), dessen Seehöhe 1765 Meter beträgt. Und sowohl St. Christoph als auch die Passhöhe selbst liegen im Gemeindegebiet von St. Anton am Arlberg. Noch mehr auf dem Arlberg drauf geht nicht.

Comment: Aha, danke für die Aufklärung (dann würde man als Deutscher vermutlich **am** Arlberg - **Pass** besser verstehen).