# "Auf" for public institutions?

Tags: word-choice, preposition

> Wie komme ich auf die Lorenzkirche?

OR

> Wie komme ich in die Lorenzkirche?

My teacher said that "in" is the right choice in this situation but I know that "auf" can be used to point direction as well when talking about public institutions. Or am I wrong? Are there any exceptions to the rule?

Comment: Note there is a Bavarian dialect form of "nach" which uses "auf". *Der Huber braucht an neien Anzug - Er fahrt heut' **auf** Minga oan kafa*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word *in* means to go inside a building, a city or another location. Thus, saying

> Wie komme ich in die Lorenzkirche?

translates to "How do I get into the Lorenzkirche?" and is the correct preposition.

The word *auf* means to go on top of something. So saying

> Wie komme ich auf die Lorenzkirche?

Would imply you want to climb on the roof. However, you use it if you want to visit the church tower.

> "Ich möchte auf den Kirchturm gehen."

Because the Kirchturm is a tall enough building, this construction works. The same works for high buildings.

> Wenn Du in New York bist, musst Du unbedingt aufs Empire State Building.

edit:
As pointed out in the comments. You can also go on top of a large area, like the famous Alexanderplatz in Berlin or the Markt / Marktplatz.

Comment: The same works for open places, for example `Wie komme ich auf den Alexanderplatz`, although `zum` or `zur` might be more appropriate when you're asking for directions from further away.

Comment: But what about public places such as "Markt" and "Bank"? How come "auf die Bank" is correct? ARE THERE ANY EXCEPTIONS TO THE RULE?

Comment: You can't say "Ich gehe auf die Bank", unless you literally mean it. You can say however "Ich bringe Geld auf die Bank". At least I have the imagination, that you stack your money, which explains the word "auf". If you just want to go to the building, you say "Ich gehe zur Bank."

Comment: @infinitezero But there is _ich gehe auf das Gymnasium/ auf das Standesamt etc_ were ppl are not going on top if the building. So there seems to be something about that rule that Rare's teacher mentioned...

Comment: @infinitezero: "Ich gehe auf die Bank." is indeed used in some dialects, but not in Hochdeutsch.

Answer (score 2):

What you actually want to say is

> Wie komme ich **zur** Lorenzkirche

This means: how can i reach it; independently of what I am doing then: entering it, climbing its roof, or whatever.

For the meanings of *in die* and *auf die* see Infinitezero*s answer on this page. But please be aware that you have to use a definite article:

> Wie komme ich **in die** Lorenzkirche?

You could say that when you find it with closed doors and you are wondering what to do to get access into the church. If you leave the *die* out, people would understand you anyway, but they would immediately understand that you do not speak the language well.

> Wie komme ich **auf die** Lorenzkirche?

You could say that when you wanted to climb its roof. A fire fighter could ask this question when the church is burning and he needs to climb it to fight the fire from above.

Fun fact: You can also say

> Wie komme ich auf die Lorenzkirche?

when that church came just to your mind, for no obvious reason, and you wonder why it did. *Auf etwas kommen* means "to come up with something", e.g. something like an an idea"

Comment: I read somewhere that "auf" can be used when talking about public locations and knowing that "bank" and"markt" are compatible  with "auf"  I thought that "Kirche" was as well. Are there any other public spaces that can use "auf" as a preposition? Maybe for "schule"?

Answer (score 0):

"Auf welche Schule gehst du" means *to visit one certain school regularly*. But we say otherwise regularly "morgen werden ich wieder in die Schule gehen". The reason for that might be--if you are interested in my speculation:

1. that certain important institutions had been built on hills. At least that situation is allegedly the case for "auf St. Pauli" (a borough named after [a church?] named after a saint); Also, *bank* (the financial institution, mentioned in a comment because of *Geld auf der Bank*) is very significantly homophone with small *Erhebungen* (hills, river banks, sand banks), and I'm not sure the homophony were coincidental, although the savings bank is traditionally explained as a bench, the proverbial table in "put money on the table", but either way it's semantically *up*.
2. Specifically for schools, a comparison to En. *off* would work as far as "went off" means *to have visited and graduated*; Although, that is rather *abgehen*, see *Schulabgänger*, the roots are deceptively similar in Proto-European *Hep-. I'm simplifying there, I have no solid reason to assume that various roots and meanings go back to a single root, and *upo "up" seems to be a bigger contrast (even if reconstructed as *h3ewp-) to the various *h2- prepositions, including those for English *in, on, under, off, of*; You can tell that there's been confusion involved, if the root of *up* is supposed to have once meant "under" a couple of millenia ago, according to the Indo-European theory. Anyhow, *ab* means *away from*, so nobody is thinking of it that way.

Other places that one can stand-on exist, too, obviously. For example, we go *on the street*, that is *auf der Straße* and we go *auf die Straße* (I am not sure whether that's *onto* or also just *on*). By the way, we say *unter Leuten* "between people, in public company".

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are referring to something like

> Ich muss heute auf das Einwohnermeldeamt/auf die Polizeiwache

This only applies, if one is addressing the institution as opposed to building/location . For locations there is a separate question [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/2543/1696).