# When to use 'bei', 'an', or 'in'

Tags: preposition

Is there a general trend or rule of when to use `bei`, `an`, or `in` when you are mentioning a place?

For instance this sentence: `Der Zug hält am Krankenhaus`. The train stops at the hospital. I thought `bei` was a more appropriate in this case. `Der Zug hält beim Krankenhaus`. The reason why I thought `bei` was more appropriate is because usually when first started to learn `bei` it is associated with buildings and such and `an` with smaller objects. But I've come across lots of sentences that seem to use them interchangeably.

For `in` am I correct in thinking that you use it when you want to express intent of entering a building or an object?

Comment: Both *Der Zug hält beim/am Krankenhaus* are correct.

Comment: There's no answer in finite time ;)

Comment: @infinitezero That question doesn't talk about _an_ though.

Comment: from @infinitezero 's question, I found this https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2540/is-there-a-rule-which-preposition-to-use-for-a-place ... = there are many questions about prepositions already and every has a different starting view point

Answer (score 0):

**An** means *right at that place*, while **bei** means *near to it*.

To get a grip of this, let's introduce a question. You are asking someone in the train for directions.

> Wo muss ich denn aussteigen, wenn ich zum Theater will?

There are four ways to answer this using *bei* and/or *an*:

> Der Zug hält am Krankenhaus. Das ist beim Theater. *(right at the hospital/theatre near to the stop)*
>
> Der Zug hält beim Krankenhaus. Das ist am Theater. *(near to the hospital/ theatre at that place)*
>
> Der Zug hält beim Krankenhaus. Das ist beim Theater. *(near to the hospital/ theatre near to the stop)*
>
> Der Zug hält am Krankenhaus. Das ist am Theater. *(right at the hospital/ theatre at that place)*